# Multiline текст в checkedListBox с#(winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть варианты с очень длинным текстом, хотелось бы сделать перенос на другую строчку.Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WPF? Winforms? откуда это?

Comment: winforms, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: [это?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5937779/312041)

Comment: похоже, но у меня чеклист.

Comment: ну сделайте чеклист по тому же принципу

Comment: Из коробки он так не умеет. Можно сделать через DataGridView. Интересует?

Comment: любые методы подойдут)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте новый проект с формой. Обзовите форму `MainForm`. Киньте на форму `DataGridView`, обзовите его `dataGridView`. И скопируйте этот код:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn _checkCol;
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn _textCol;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _checkCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        _checkCol.Name = "CheckCol";
        _checkCol.HeaderText = "CheckCol";
        _checkCol.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
        _checkCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;

        var textColCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        textColCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        _textCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        _textCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        _textCol.Name = "TextCol";
        _textCol.HeaderText = "TextCol";
        _textCol.DefaultCellStyle = textColCellStyle;
        _textCol.ReadOnly = true;


        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
        dataGridView.CellMouseDown += dataGridView_CellMouseDown;
        dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        dataGridView.MultiSelect = false;
        dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {
            _checkCol,
            _textCol
        });

        dataGridView.Rows.Add(true, "Какой то очень длиный текст который не влезает в одну строку");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(false, "Какой то очень длиный текст который не влезает в одну строку");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(true, "Какой то очень длиный текст который не влезает в одну строку");
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(false, "Какой то очень длиный текст который не влезает в одну строку");
        dataGridView.ClearSelection();
    }

    private void dataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if (row.Selected) {
            row.Cells[_checkCol.Index].Value = !(bool)row.Cells[_checkCol.Index].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вернулся к этому же вопросу. Надеюсь вы ответите) А как смоделировать работу checkedlistbox'а?