# С# winforms Как сделать из DataGridView checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms

[Multiline текст в checkedListBox с#(winforms)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950230/multiline-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-checkedlistbox-%D1%81winforms) - Код взял отсюда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - Вышло вот так, всё работает.

Как из DataGridView функционально сделать CheckedListBox? Так же у меня был код, чтобы можно было выбрать только 1 вариант.

```
        private void cSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CheckedItems.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int g = 0; g < this.Items.Count; g++)
                this.SetItemChecked(g, false);
            this.SetItemChecked(this.SelectedIndex, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Как из DataGridView функционально сделать CheckedListBox?` зачем? Почему бы просто не использовать CheckedListBox ?

Comment: @tym32167, в него не влезает длинный текст. Нам такое не подходит,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Пишу не в комментарий по причине отсутствия 50 репутации на момент написания*

Во-первых, необходимость в большом количестве текста в компонентах CheckBox говорит о плохом проектном решении. Настоятельно рекомендую вам пересмотреть дизайн и логику программы.

Во-вторых, если функционала CheckedListBox вам недостаточно, я бы посоветовал использовать несколько компонентов типа CheckBox, расположенных при необходимости в каком-нибудь контейнере, например Panel. CheckBox имеет свойство AutoSize, и при необходимости текст можно разбить на любое количество строк, главное указать правильный размер компонента.

В-третьих, если вам необходима возможность выбрать только один вариант, то для данных целей необходимо использовать несколько компонентов типа RadioButton (в первую очередь, потому что данный компонент подразумевает выбор ТОЛЬКО ОДНОГО варианта), объединенных в какой-либо контейнер. Выбор любого RadioButton в контейнере приводит к снятию выбора со всех остальных RadioButton в данном контейнере автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Интересные варианты, попробую их реализовать.

Comment: @PavelKutsubin будут вопросы по реализации - обращайтесь